# <form:form> inside <c:forEach> with modelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

```
<c:forEach items="${someList}" var="variable">
        <form:form name="myForm ${variable.value}"
            action="Foo" method="POST"
            modelAttribute="attribute"> // I am using model attribute from c:foreach variable
                    <form:input //it says error is in here
                        value="${attribute.name}" path="name" />

                <button type="submit">Commit</button>
        </form:form>
    </c:forEach>
```

Edit: I changed the code so every form gets different name and so far it works, but modelAttribute cannot be obtained from c:forEach variable.

Comment: This will create a new form (with same name) for every element present inside the List, which may cause problems. We can declare form outside the loop and create the elements inside it based on list contents.

Comment: It creates multi forms with same name so gives an error.